# Compare WebORB vs LCDS and FMS vs Wowza

Tags: flash-media-server, weborb, wowza, lcds

Hello please give comparison details as per follow 1) FMS vs Wowza vs Red5 and 2) WebORB vs LCDS vs BlazeDS

I am eager to review the feedback.

Specially compare with respect to no of concurrent users support and support of data-management( use of data-management-config.xml). My application will be having wast no of concurrent users accessing the application. So load barring must be high and consistent.

Any proper reply would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

BlazeDS does not support data management nor RTMP, which would be necessary if you needed to do data push or real-time client synchronization.

WebORB for Java and LCDS both support much larger numbers of concurrent users (thousands per CPU). Unfortunately the exact number is much less a function of the integration server than it is a combination of your hardware, application complexity, bandwidth, memory, web services vs remoting, etc. This is why load testing your own application is important.

Assuming LCDS and WebORB for Java are on par in terms of performance, scalability and features for remoting, messaging and data management, the question then becomes ease of use and cost. Oh...and one more thing, WebORB streams media at no additional cost.

Answer (score 0):

I have also read about LCDS community edition (subset of LCDS ES).
Neways it does not support real time data push means data management.
WebORB is much more better, convenient and effort-able compare to  LCDS ES.
And it has WDMF(WebORB Data Management for Flex) against LCDS's FDMS I think u aware of what it is.

Newys thanks for the tip.
I have already developed the whole project using LCDS ES and now will have to start everything from scratch to shift my source code to WebORB.

And yes what about Wowza and FMS comparison?